# Flat reservations optimization system

Tags: optimization

i have a booking system and i need to write a script that optimize the reservations.

When a customer book a flat, the system assigns the first flat available. The problem is that after a few reservations my "grid" become fragmented.

Grid example:

[Grid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5bJw.png)

In practice I need to minimize the white space so as I can accept the maximum number of reservations.
My question is: there are some know problem that fit my problem? I had thought to some knapsack problem variations.
I can provide more info if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scheduling problem. One very important question is: can you reassign a flat to a different number once the reservation has been made?

- If the answer is yes, you will find a solution if and only if you have no day with more reservations than you have flats: simply take the first idle slot of the very first day d1, and if there is a conflict with a future reservation, reallocate the future reservation by taking the first idle slot of its very first day d2 (note that d2>d1), and your algorithm will converge because you will have a strictly increasing sequence of days where you need reallocation.
- If the answer is no, we come into a tricky world where your algorithm has to guess what would be the future reservations. A good heurisic, I think, would be to score the placements. For instance, you can check how many iddle slots you leave before and after the reservation, and take the option that leaves a few empty slots as possible.